# Range of $k$ in exponential equation

Tags: algebra-precalculus

If all the solution of the equation $k^{\cos x}+k^{-\cos x}=6(k>1)$ are real. Then the set of values of $k$ is

solution i try

put $k^{\cos x}=t(t>0)$  our equation  is $t^2-6t+1=0$

$$t=\frac{6\pm \sqrt{32}}{2}=(3\pm 2\sqrt{2})=k^{\cos x}\leq k$$

how i find maximum bound on $k$ .Help me

Comment: There are two variables here: $x$ and $k$. For *any* $k \ge 3 + 2\sqrt 2$, I can set $$x = \cos^{-1} \log_k (3 + 2\sqrt 2)$$ So from the information given, there is no upper bound on $k$. Were there any other restrictions to your problem?

Comment: answer given  is $k\in[3+2\sqrt{2},\infty)$. required explanation thanks

Comment: Why were you asking for a maximum bound then, when the answer indicates that $k$ is *not* bounded above?